# how to use deberta model from hugging face and use .compile() and . summary() with it

Tags: python, nlp, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-datasets

I used this code to load weights

```
from transformers import DebertaTokenizer, DebertaModel
import torch

tokenizer = DebertaTokenizer.from_pretrained('microsoft/deberta-base')
model = DebertaModel.from_pretrained('microsoft/deberta-base')
```

after that i want to optimize and use loss function using compile function

```
model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=5e-5),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=tf.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy(),
)
```

I got this error
AttributeError: 'DebertaModel' object has no attribute 'compile'

Comment: Tensorflow based models has a compile and summary function. But this model pytorch based

Comment: thank you but how to use compile with it cuz i use keras in my code

Comment: you can use when library support it.

Answer (score 2):

The transformers library offers a tensorflow-based model `TFDebertaModel`.
Replace DebertaModel with TFDebertaModel and the execution of compile() works.

I changed your snippet to the following and compile works. Try this:

```
from transformers import DebertaTokenizer, TFDebertaModel
```

Tested with transformers version: 4.19.2

https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.19.2/en/model_doc/deberta#transformers.TFDebertaModel

Answer (score 1):

the only way to work on it using pytorch library